# MUI 5 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up'), When using makestyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have recently build a react app with MUI-5 and it was working fine but now i am facing a weird issue where my app won't start and i see bunch of mui errors. These errors occurred after i deleted the yarn.lock file and freshly added all packages. I have tried every solution but its not working.

Error:

> MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
> You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')

**package.json file**:

```
    {
      "name": "doctor",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.11.0",
        "@date-io/moment": "^2.11.0",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
        "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.62",
        "@mui/material": "^5.10.7",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.10.7",
        "@mui/system": "^5.10.6",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.22.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "@types/react-qr-reader": "^2.1.4",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.35",
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
        "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.21",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/react-table": "^7.7.9",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21"
      },
      "resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "17.0.2",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
      }
  }
```

**app.tsx file;**

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "./App.css";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
// redux
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store, { persistor } from "./redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

// Routes
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import history from "./redux/history";
import Router from "./Router";
// Theme
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";
import CustomSnackbarProvider from "./providers/CustomSnackbarProvider";

import muiTheme from "./constants/theme";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler,
  BarElement,
} from "chart.js";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import AccessControlWrapper from "./components/AccessControlWrapper";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  ChartDataLabels,
  Filler
);

declare var process: {
  env: {
    REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY: string;
    REACT_APP_STRIPE_CLIENT_SECRET: string;
  };
};

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
              <SnackbarProvider
                maxSnack={3}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "center",
                }}
              >
                <CustomSnackbarProvider>
                  <AccessControlWrapper>
                    <Router />
                  </AccessControlWrapper>
                </CustomSnackbarProvider>
              </SnackbarProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </Elements>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

theme config file:

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: true; // removes the `xs` breakpoint
    sm: true;
    md: true;
    lg: true;
    xl: true;
    xxl: true;
  }
}

const theme = {
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "#FBFBFB",
    },
    primary: {
      light: "#9D9DA5",
      main: "#2EC2A5",
      contrastText: "#fff",
    },
    secondary: {
      light: "#ff7961",
      main: "#24344B",
      dark: "#ba000d",
      contrastText: "#000",
    },
  },
};

const BREAKPOINTS = {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600,
  md: 900,
  lg: 1200,
  xl: 1536,
  xxl: 1800,
};

let muiTheme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: BREAKPOINTS,
  },
  ...theme,
});
export default muiTheme;
```

**Styles.tsx**

```
import { Theme } from "@mui/system";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";


export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  intro: {
    padding: "0 2rem",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
      padding: "0 4rem !important",
    },
  },
}));
```

I've been stuck with this problem for couple of days. I don't know what i am doing wrong. i have already wrapped my routes with **ThemeProvider** but still its throwing these errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#using-the-theme-context):

> #### Using the theme context
>
> Starting from v5, MUI no longer uses JSS as its default styling solution. If you still want to use the utilities exported by `@mui/styles` and they depend on the `theme`, you will need to provide the `theme` as part of the context. For this, you can use the `ThemeProvider` component available in `@mui/styles`, or, if you are already using `@mui/material`, you should use the one exported from `@mui/material/styles` so that the same `theme` is available for components from '@mui/material'.

So your `Styles.tsx` should be like:

```
import { Theme } from "@mui/system";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
//import muiTheme from "./constants/...";

export const useStyles = makeStyles((muiTheme) => ({
  intro: {
    padding: "0 2rem",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
      padding: "0 4rem !important",
    },
  },
}));
```

And be aware:

> ⚠️ `@mui/styles` is the ***legacy*** styling solution for MUI. It depends on **JSS** as a styling solution, which is not used in the `@mui/material` anymore, deprecated in v5.

And

> ⚠️ `@mui/styles` is not compatible with **React.StrictMode** or **React 18**.

So I recommend using better solutions like `styled` or `sx` prop.

Comment: where we using the theme var? and i tried the above solution it's not working still same error, and yeah i am aware that its deprecated and will not be available in v6 but my project is already too big and i don't have that kind of time to migrate it and use the sx props coz a lot components are already styled with makestyle

Comment: The theme is used as an argument for the `makeStyles` function. try the edited code

Comment: still not working and i don't think we can pass theme as argument